# OnCreate in Application class called twice

Tags: android

I didn't use `android:process` in my `AndroidManifest`. When I launch app `oncreate` in `Application` class get called twice. I would like to know what could cause such behaviour.

Comment: how did you know it was called twice? are you sure you don't have two logs in there? also, could you make sure whatever you doing in there isn't initializing the app again?

Comment: It has just one log statement and it printed twice.

Comment: I am starting a service in that method.

Comment: show your manifest and application file.

Comment: please we could not make a guess why you are receiving this so share your code here

Comment: Sorry, I can not share code

Answer (score -1):

Probably you call your service when you run your app. 
Use this to prevent recalling the service several times:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourService.class);
        if (!IsServiceRunning(YourService.class)) {
            startService(intent);
        }
```

Use this function to check whether the service is running or not:

```
public boolean IsServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The start of a service will not trigger the applications onCreate. Only, to start an exported service form outside the app, the application needs to be created first. But the next creation of this service won't trigger the applications onCreate again.